# Can the FAA 8130-3 have "modified" status if a part is converted by replacing piece-parts from IPC?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance

I have been trying to identify if the [FAA 8130-3 Instructions](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentid/1021686) have some clarity but am unable to deduce if this situation is indeed acceptable. A sequence of events (Of sorts) is given below:

- A Part had a defect and was removed as Unserviceable and shipped to Shop
- The Shop has replaced certain piece-parts which are fitted on a newer design
- The Shop has then released the original part with the FAA 8130-3 stating "Modified" in Block 11
- As per the Shop, the replacement Modifies the part and the status in Block 11 is acceptable